# How can I load data into an S3 bucket from a Twilio function?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, twilio

I've written the following Twilio function to load data into an S3 bucket.

However, no data ever gets to S3 at all.

What's wrong?

```html
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    callback(null,
        putFile(
            getParams(context, event)
        )
    );
};

function getParams(context, event) {
    return {
        Bucket: 'my-bucket',
        Key: 'my-file.json',
        Body: JSON.stringify(event),
        ContentType: 'application/json'
    };
}

function putFile(params) {
    var aws = require('aws-sdk');
    var s3 = new aws.S3();

    s3.putObject(params, (err, res) => {
        if (err) console.log(`s3-err: ${err}`);
        if (res) console.log(`s3-res: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) maybe?

Comment: There is a Twilio blog post you may be able to extract some useful (external S3 storage piece) information from. Encrypting and Storing Twilio Flex Recordings Off-site - https://www.twilio.com/blog/encrypt-store-twilio-flex-recordings-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asnwer to my question is here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/invocation#callback-and-asynchronous-limitations

> Callback and Asynchronous Limitations
>
> It is important to note that when the callback function is invoked, it
>   will terminate all execution of your Function. This includes any
>   asynchronous processes you may have kicked off during during the
>   execution of your handler.
>
> For this reason, if you are using libraries that are natively
>   asynchronous, you need to nest your call to the callback function
>   inside the promise handler.

So, basically, `callback();` needs to be placed inside the successful response of the request to S3.

I failed to do that in my code snippet above, as I simply logged the response. When I placed the `callback();` out, I instructed the process to terminate, and any API request to uploading data to S3 would never complete.

Here's a simplified snippet that works:

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
    S3.upload(getParams(context, event), function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            callback(error);
        } else {
            callback(null, "Data Uploaded");
        }
    });
};
```

This is it. Hope it helps others. Cheers! =)